# How can I define an object type with one value if the key is in an array and another value if not

Tags: typescript

I have a function something like:

```
function allFinished(pendingProps: string[], allProps: Record<string, unknown>): boolean {
    return pendingProps.every((pendingProp) => allProps[pendingProp].isFinished)
}
```

For typescript to be happy with me, it needs to know that each `allProps` key which is an element of `pendingProps` will have a value that includes `isFinished`. But I also need it to be okay with keys which are not in `pendingProps` having a different value type.

This would be fairly simple if pendingProps was defined ahead of time and could be marked `as const`, but I can't figure out how to do this with with an arbitrary string array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should make `allFinished` generic for this to be properly typed.

```
function allFinished<
  T extends Record<K, { isFinished: boolean }> & Record<string, unknown>, 
  K extends string
>(pendingProps: K[], allProps: T): boolean {
    return pendingProps.every((pendingProp) => allProps[pendingProp].isFinished)
}
```

The essentially expresses the constraints you mentioned in your question. All `pendingProps` will be stored in `K` while the `allProps` object is stored in `T`. `T` is constrained so that every property where the key is part of `K` must have a property `isFinished`. But every other `string` property will have an unknown type.

Let's see if this works:

```
allFinished(["a", "b", "c"], {
    a: { isFinished: true },
    b: { isFinished: false },
    c: {},  // Error: Property 'isFinished' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ isFinished: boolean; }'
    d: {}
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=3&pln=9&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwDaoGIzDAzgCwFMATAHgFgAoRRAFUUIA8pCxjdEAlQiOAJzIBpADSIA3ojxYcBEgC5EAIzhxUhZEgC%20APkQAyLj35lcUPtgDmo8AGswcAO5htoqjUENmrdolPmwFlTaABQADt6WAAp8cKG4CoIA2gC6omio0bHxdACUCsqq6khibjSIfIRQIHxI4WxRMXEAdIQAboR8AJ7BYREBmaE5iAC8uukDuIl1xA2xyU1S2HhExDlUmlSblOnSyyTBiQBEyIeih4qniIcQh6nipTTIChKLMisKZiCEiJrCD0rPSS4XayYgKYBoXDfX7-CDPX40AD0iMQAFE%20DE%20AoBh0oJ1EAByV57YgEoGIAC2eFwlkkSDx4UJYk0ZMUICg5UIAEcQDAKsQ6YgGd8CS9gUtQfkVGoNABuH4E-5g8QbSiaHJAA)

Comment: That works! Thank you. I'd been trying things with generics but I didn't realize you could use K the way you did.